# Node js and mysql with bluebird

Tags: mysql, node.js, bluebird

I'm trying to use bluebird with mysql.

So I have

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var Mysql   = Promise.promisifyAll(require('mysql'))
```

but after ?

I tried with

```
var pool = Mysql.createPoolAsync({
connectionLimit : 10,
host : MYSQL_HOST,
database : MYSQL_DB,
user : MYSQL_USER,
password : MYSQL_PASS
})


pool.getConnectionAsync().then( (error,connection) => { console.log('----') } )
```

But it's not working.

```
TypeError: pool.getConnectionAsync is not a function
```

Answer (score 2):

`mysql` doesn't expose the other methods in it's exports, so you need to promisify them directly.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql/lib/Connection").prototype);
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql/lib/Pool").prototype);
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben Fortune.   It's working using `mysql.createPool` and `ool.getConnectionAsync().then`.  But I don't understand why ?  How can I learn finding your solution.  Nodejs is not so easy that I thought.

Comment: You can find it [here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/working-with-callbacks.html#more-common-examples) in the documentation